# Comic/Bande dessinée about a child who finds a spaceship as tiny as a toy, turns out to be dangerous

Tags: story-identification, comics, bandes-dessinees

I'm looking for a French comic that I 'read' while in France about 25 years ago - I could not read much French at the time, which is why I only have very hazy ideas about the plot.

Protagonist was a child who found a spaceship, which was as tiny as a toy. He/she took it home. The ship had some sort of ray-based main weapon, the effects of which where dangerous, so the child effectively had a raygun.

The style of the comic was not manga, more in the vein of the usual French/Belgian comics. Language was French, and I would wager the artist was French/Belgian as well. The comic was targeted at children and young adults, I guess.

The comic was a short series, with the child having several adventures related to the spaceship-finding and the ensuing drama.

Comment: Oh, I think I have that one. _Charly_. Let me get to a computer and I'll post that as an answer :)

Comment: "Le petite hommes" ( Pierre Seron, the series is from the 60s) also had spaceships and other futuristic-looking contraptions in some of their stories, although I don't remember a kids and a railgun (still, if you enjoyed the one from your description you will probably love this one, too).

Comment: @Jenayah I just googled Charly, and that is indeed the one i meant. Thanks! (It does not seem to have been translated to either german or english, which explains why my googling did not turn it up...)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[*Charly*](https://www.bedetheque.com/serie-683-BD-Charly.html) by Belgian authors Magda and Lapière, a French-speaking bande dessinée published between 1991 and 2007.

> Protagonist was a child who found a spaceship, which was as tiny as a toy. He/she took it home.

Charly, a six-years-old, is offered a Cap'tain Foudre (Cap'n Lighting) model rocket by his father. It's quickly revealed that the toy can think and act for itself, and will do *anything* to please the child's unconscious desires, including murder.

> The ship had some sort of ray-based main weapon, the effects of which where dangerous, so the child effectively had a raygun.

Below is an extract of the first issue, *Jouet d'enfer* (*A toy from hell*). This is the first time we see the toy acting for itself: Charly is playing in a park and a German Shepherd attacks him; the rocket reacts by blasting the dog with the raygun you remembered.

[image: Charly is attacked by a dog and the toy uses a ray blast]

> The comic was a short series, with the child having several adventures related to the spaceship-finding and the ensuing drama.

The drama you referred to was likely the army going against the toy, since a war weapon should obviously not be handled by a young child. Overall, the series has 13 issues, but it's divided in cycles, not all of them including the toy; only the 4 first issues deal with it, the rest drift a bit.

Below is the cover of the first issue, *Jouet d'enfer*.

[image: Charly issue 1 cover]

---

Found partly by memory, confirmed with the Google query `vaisseau jouet site:ederweld.fr` since I knew I was likely to have first read about it on this particular site - and indeed, there's [a "weekly reading recommendation" about it](http://ederweld.fr/conseil-lecture-de-la-semaine-charly-de-lapiere-et-magda/)!